# Does the cohomology Bockstein homomorphism map to the homology Bockstein homomorphism under Poincarè duality?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cohomology, homology, short-exact-sequences, poincare-duality

Given a manifold $X$ and short exact sequence of abelian groups
$$
1\rightarrow A_1\overset{\iota}{\rightarrow} A_2\overset{\pi}{\rightarrow} A_3\rightarrow 1
$$
we get the Bockstein map in cohomology $\beta : H^p(X,A_3)\rightarrow H^{p+1}(X,A_1)$. On cochains this is defined as follows. Choose a section $s:A_3\rightarrow A_2$, then given $f\in Z^p(X,A_3)$, $s(f)\in C^{p}(X,A_2)$ is not closed, but $\pi(\delta (s(f)))=0$ and thus there exists $\beta(f)\in Z^{p+1}(X,A_1)$ such that $\iota(\beta(f))=\delta s(f)$. In a similar way one can define the Bockstein map in homology $b : H_k(X,A_3)\rightarrow H_{k-1}(X,A_1)$. On a chain $c\in Z_k(X,A_3)$ this is defined such that $\iota(b(c))=\partial s(c)$. In the last equation for any map $m : A\rightarrow B$ (even not a homomorphism) of abelian groups and $c\in C_k(X,A)$ I denoted by $m(c)\in C_k(X,B)$ the chains obtained by acting with $m$ on the coefficients.

On the other hand, if $X$ is orientable, by using Poincarè duality $\Phi_A :H_p(X,A)\rightarrow H^{d-p}(X,A)$ for homology/cohomology we induce a map in homology $b': H_p(X,A_3)\rightarrow H_{p-1}(X,A_1)$ as follows. Given $c\in H_p(X,A_3)$, construct $\Phi _{A_3}(c)\in H^{d-p}(X,A_3)$, and then by using the Bockstein $\beta(\Phi_{A_3}(c))\in H^{d-p+1}(X,A_1)$. Then define
$$
b'(c)=\Phi_{A_1}^{-1}\left(\beta(\Phi_{A_3}(c))\right)
$$

It is natural to expect that $b'=b$ but this does not seem to me totally obvious. I tried to prove it but at some point I need to use $\Phi$ on non-closed cycles (which I don't know how much is legal) and I would need to prove that this action commutes with the section $s:A_3\rightarrow A_2$, and I don't know how to do this...

Comment: Your SES of abelian groups needs to be a SES of unital rings for this to work; then the answer of Dave should work in this generality since the quasisomorphism he describes is given by capping with a chain representing the fundamental class, and this yields a map of SES of chain complexes by a quick check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found another proof you might prefer as Lemma 2.4 of this paper:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.03754.pdf.
It's stated only for one case of groups, but I don't see why it wouldn't extend more generally.
Note that the Poincar'e duality isomorphism is given by the cap product with a fundamental class. That's the inverse of the map you denote $\Phi$.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking at. Do you means it should hold not only for the SES $1\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow 1$ but for any SES?

Comment: Yes indeed the paper refers to a book where the statement is proven for a generic SES of abelian groups!

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure I quite understand your formulation of the question (what, for example, is a section $s\colon A_3 \to A_1$?) but the following is probably what you're looking for. Given a closed oriented manifold $X$ of dimension $d$ there is a quasi-isomorphism at the level of cochains and chains $C^*(X,\mathbb{Z}) \to \Sigma^{-d}C_*(X,\mathbb{Z})$. These are complexes of free abelian groups, so if you tensor this with your short exact sequence of abelian groups, you get the statement that the Bockstein homomorphisms agree in cohomology and homology.

Comment: About the section is was a typo (I copied and pasted so it appeared twice), which I now corrected: the section is $s:A_3\rightarrow A_2$. Thank you for the answer. So if I understand correctly this implies that, denoting by $\Phi _A :C_p(X,A)\rightarrow C^{d-p}(X,A)$ Poincarè duality on chains (which I understand is somehow a meaningful thing), this commutes with the section, namely $\Phi_{A_2}(s(c))=s(\Phi_{A_3}(c))$, where $c\in C_p(X,A_3)$. Is this tautological from the definition of Poincarè duality? If not, is there a simple way to prove it directly?

Comment: Dave, up to a $(-1)^d$ sign as per your argument.

Comment: @DaveBenson in this case I am not sure I understand your answer. Does your answer refer to Poincarè duality? My question was specifically about Poincarè duality and I was trying to unpack the Poincarè dual of the Bockstein in homology and compare it with the Bockstein in cohomology. This makes sense since both are homomorphisms between the same two cohomology group, so they either are equal or not equal. This was my question.